# Starting mincha early

Tags: halacha, zemanim, mincha-afternoon-prayer

Since we are entering the winter (in the northern hemisphere) many people try to daven mincha at mincha gedolah. I have been told that waiting for a half hour after mid-day is a way of ensuring that one does not accidentally daven before mid-day and there are those who state that someone who makes a mistake and davens within that time period does not have to repeat Mincha.

Note that "a half hour" is actually *shaos zmaniyos* rather than 30 clock minutes and mid-day (*chatzos*) is calculated based on sunrise and sunset.

[Times for Mincha](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=When_Is_the_Earliest_and_Latest_Time_to_Pray%3F#Times_for_Mincha)

> If one prayed prior to six and a half hours, according to many one has
>   not fulfilled one’s obligation, however, some say that one has
>   fulfilled one's obligation after the fact. <sup>[30]</sup>

[note 30](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=When_Is_the_Earliest_and_Latest_Time_to_Pray%3F#cite_note-30)

> [30] Mishna Brurah 233:2 writes that this is implied from Shulchan
>   Aruch 233:1 (and is agreed upon by many achronim), however there are
>   some achronim who say that after the fact one has fulfilled one’s
>   obligation. Kaf HaChaim 233:2 quotes the dispute of the achronim but
>   concludes that because Tefillah is derabbanan one does not have to
>   pray again.

Does the time specification start at the very beginning of Mincha or as of *Shmone Esrai*. The difference would be starting *Ashrei*. While this is not really a time difference during the week, Shabbos Mincha could be as much as 10 minutes earlier. Similarly this could apply to a Ta'anis Tzibur since we must read the Torah.

The answer to this question could also make a difference according to those who say one is not Yotzei bed'avad.

Comment: Note the premise that you could time this so precisely is pretty ridiculous http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13226/759

Comment: Is there any obligation to say Ashrei before Mincha? It's hard to imagine how there could be one. We (Ashkenazim) don't do so on Yom Kippur for instance.

Comment: Note that there are opinons that in the winter one should wait 30 regular minutes. See Mishna Beruah Shaar Hatizyun 233:8 and the notes from the Dirshu Editon and the notes in Piskei Teshuvot.

Answer (score 1):

[Minchas Yitzchak 6:53](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1599&pgnum=355) allows one to do Kriyas Hatorah in the half hour after Chatzos, so long the actual Shemona Esrei is done after 6.5 hours (Zemaniot).

This was in response to a question regarding a fast day (Asara B'Teveis on a Friday). I do not know if this would be the case for a Shabbos Mincha or a regular fast day not on Friday.

Answer (score 0):

Today we discussed this topic about an other question.  In [SA OC  233, 1](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%92_%D7%90). If one has prayed Mincha between Chatsot and chatsot + 1/2 hour,  Magen Avraham  and SA disqualified even bediavad.

Baer Heytev in name of Yad Aharon and Bet Yaaqov stated that bediavad the tefila is good enough. Mishna Berura also reported this seemingly Lehalacha. 
Aruch Hashulchan also stated,  on the basis of Peri Chaddash that Bediavad Yatsa.  All this concern Amida only,  which is compared to  korban Tamid of ben Haarbayim. But Ashre is only a lecture of one psalm. It's never prohibited. Kriat Hatora is not either compared to Korban Ben Haarbayim. Obviously there is no prohibition.

Gemara Yoma 28b said that the reason for which korban Tamid of ben Haarbayim did not start before 6 + 1/2 is that we are less Baki than Avraham. But all this seems to be yet  a kind of Lechtecilla despite that Erev Pessach on Erev Shabbat is a special leniency.  And this ambiguity is the source of the machloket Haposkim.

Comment: The question was if 6:30 mincha gedola includes ashrei and torah reading, or not.  This is a lechatchila question or it should ask from 6. Your reference is to bedieved if you are yotzei the amida, and I dont see how you address the quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

Piskei Teshuva (Rabinowitz) 233/1 1st # brings MBerura is not yotzei tefila bedieved after 6 before 6:30, and there are those that are yotzei bedieved.  Commenting there he says (bracket numbers are his footnotes):

> even the saying of Korbonot(2) and Arshrei(3) should be after 6:30.  And
>   also(4) on Shabbat and fast days dont read the Torah before 6:30.

His inclusion of fast days would argue on Minchas Yitzchach brought on this thread, but even there the MY allows only when Shas haDachat - when pushed.  I would be interested to see anyone who says Lechatchila you can start earlier than 6:30.

His footnoted on this
(2)Q&A (shut) Sharga HaMeir 7/1 - since korbanot are said in reference to the tamid, and the tamid is not offered until after 6:30.
(3)Q&A [Tzitz Eliezer 10/20](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14509&st=&pgnum=104&hilite=)
(4)Q&A [Tzitz Eliezer 10/20](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14509&st=&pgnum=104&hilite=)

> שו"ת ציץ אליעזר חלק י סימן כ
>   ולא מיבעיא שאין לקרות בתורה לפני הגעת זמן המנחה אלא גם לרבות שלא לומר אשרי ובא לציון ופסוק ואני תפלתי, ואפרש דברי...י