# Shkiya/Netz behind a mountain

Tags: halacha, zemanim, geography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commencing Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/commencing-shabbos)

If one is located behind a mountain, what time is Shkiya or Tzeis?

1. Is it when the sun sets below the "calculated" horizon (when the sun should set had the mountain not been there)?
2. Is it when the sun sets behind the mountain?

What if one is on top of a mountain? Is Shkiya/Tzeis affected the same way?

What if one is on top of a building, is Shkiya when the sun sets for him or when it sets for people on ground level?

**PLEASE BRING SOURCES**

Comment: possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1284/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, thank you! I knew we've had this before, and couldn't find it. Anyone: any reason this should not be closed as duplicate?