# Why is elevation not factored into zmanim in places like New York?

Tags: shabbat, zemanim, geography

As you might already know, *zmanim* (for *Shabbos*, etc.) are determined by a number of factors, one being the elevation of the particular locale. But for some reason, if you check the charts and algorithms for the *zmanim* of New York (I'm thinking [Monsey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsey,_New_York) (elevation 548 feet), specifically), the elevation is not factored into the times. Any idea why this is? I know the difference would be nominal at best, but it's still a difference. We might as well use it, right? Any ideas why we don't?

Comment: Which algorithms are you looking at?

Comment: These zmanim, for instance, do not include elevation: http://www.myzmanim.com/day.aspx?vars=US10952

Comment: This information comes from someone I know who wrote algorithms for Zmanim for Shul websites, and has nowhere seems to use elevation for these places. He was wondering why.

Comment: @devir. It doesn't really answer your question, but if you open that myzmanim link and click on the picture of the mountains you can set the elevation.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I saw that. But as you said, why not factor that in to begin with?

Comment: Elevation can vary greatly even within one zip code

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1284